# How to add multiple layers to SAGA map view at the same time?

Tags: saga, mapping

I need to visually interpret more than 50 grids, so I want to add them all to a SAGA map at the same time. If I right-click on a single layer, I can "*Add to Map*", but with multiple, this option is not available.

Is there a way to do this with the command line for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can "Add to Map", but with multiple, this option is not available.

With a multiple layer selection, the name of the option is *Show*.

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick. I expected it to be called similar and never noticed the _Show_. You saved me a lot of work! :)

Comment: @Soalpa, you are welcome!